# Autenticação via redes sociais

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, autenticação, oauth

Estou implementando autenticação via *Facebook* e *Twitter*, e posteriormente outras redes, mas algumas dúvidas surgiram. *Como seria a lógica para a criação de uma nova conta quando o usuário fizesse a autenticação via rede social?*

Parto do princípio de que obtenho o `id` e o `e-mail`, mas qual seria a 'foreign key', entre minha database e a rede social?

---

> *Tomo como exemplo o código abaixo retirado de um tutorial:*

```
# baseado no ID do Facebook
select * from Users where Fuid = '$fuid'

# (IF) novo usuario
INSERT INTO User (Fuid , Femail) VALUES ('$fuid' , '$femail')

# (ELSE) atualiza dados do usuario
UPDATE Users SET Femail = '$femail' where Fuid = '$fuid'
```

No exemplo ele tomo o `id` do Facebook como base unica, insere ou atualiza o e-mail, nome e qualquer outra informação disponível.

Como eu faria para integrar as redes quando o usuário do Facebook e Twitter que tenha o mesmo e-mail? Cada autenticação retornaria um `id` diferente, então não se aplica ao código acima.

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso eu usaria uma tabela master para cadastro local do usuário e criaria tabelas para cada rede social (Face, Twt, etc) com o ID da tabela master sendo usado como chave para todas as outras tabelas. Assim, você poderia até mesmo capturar dados extras do usuário (locais?!), registrar datas de acesso feito por cada rede social (individualmente), etc.

```
|  Tabela      |          Campos         |          
+--------------+-------------------------+
| User (master)| ID | name | email | etc |
| Facebook     | ID | SID  | email | etc |
| Twitter      | ID | SID  | email | etc |
| Outra        | ID | SID  | email | etc |
|______________|____|______|_______|_____|
```

O **ID** é a chave; **SID** é o ID de cada rede social (ou token); os demais campos (**etc**) estarão a cargo da necessidade de sua aplicação.

Basta acrescentar no INSERT ou UPDATE uma sentença extra para a tabela da rede social em questão.